# Devolver o nome digitado

Tags: c, variáveis, formatação, printf

O programa só retorna a primeira letra do nome digitado. Acho que tem algo a ver com o  *"%c"*, mas ainda não entendi como funciona essa formatação ou talvez os tipos de dados em C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char nome;
    printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
    scanf("%c", &nome);
    printf("Seu nome é %c", nome);
}
```

Comment: `%c` é letra, `%s` é texto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguinte, você tem que transformar a variável 'nome' num array ou numa string. No caso, esse array será um vetor de caracteres. (Por sinal, char significa justamente caractere, por isso volta só o primeiro caractere da variável 'nome').

Então troque %c por %s que serve para strings e const*char (caracteres em sequencia [arrays]) e troque `char nome;` por `char nome[20];`. Fazendo isso você limita a imprimir uma array de 20 caracteres na variável 'nome'.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char nome[20];
    printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
    scanf("%s",nome);
    printf("Seu nome é %s", nome);

  return 0;
}
```

ps: É sempre importante tu por (return 0;) em funções 'int main', para o programa entender que terminou ali e retornar um valor interno para função, esse valor n é impresso. E eu retirei o "&", pois se não me engano ele não é necessário para arrays (char [x]), caso ocorra algum erro bote-o de volta onde estava!

Comment: Ah, sim. Entendi. Pode mostrar como seria com string?

Comment: @Lucas: em C uma string é um array de caracteres acrescido do caractere terminador '\0'.

Comment: não apenas o que o comentário acima falou. Uma string na programação "C" deve ser chamada pelo #include<string> e então contém termos próprios e uma maneira bem única de se mexer com ela. Sugiro que pesquise no google em alguns sites de programação, não sou o mais qualificado pra ajudar com essa parte.

Comment: @Cesar Czermak: em C as operações sobre strings estão definidas em <string.h>. Em C++, que não é o que o autor da pergunta especifica, já que C é diferente de C++, é que se utiliza `#include <string>` e que utilizamos para a definição de strings e suas operações..

Comment: verdade... eu esqueci de por o ".h" peço perdão por isso! Dei uma louco, foi malz... E olha que eu nem sei C++ ainda hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de criar a variável "nome" como foi feita, faça da seguinte forma:

chat nome[X];

X é um número que vive escolher (também pode ser uma variável definida antes)

Você também deve trocar o scanf(...) por isso:

fgets(nome);

Por fim, em vez do printf, use isso:

fputs(nome);

Assim, creio que o seguinte código deve funcionar:

int main(){
char nome[50];
printf("Informe seu nome: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(nome);
printf("Seu nome é: ");
fputs(nome);
}

*Eu tentei incluir a biblioteca, mas o texto ficou estranho, de qualquer forma, só usa a stdio.h, e talvez a stdlib.h (mas acredito que a última não).

Explicando o seu problema: quando você declara um char como "char c;", você está reservando APENAS o espaço de memória de um carácter, quando você declara como mostrado anteriormente, você declara "X" espaços de memória para caracteres, assim, nós chamamos de strings.
O trabalho com strings é, muitas vezes, diferente do trabalho com caracteres normais, portanto, é recomendado usar outras funções, como a fputs e a fgets.
Mais um detalhe, logo ates do scanf(...) ou fgets(...), é bom usar um "fflush (stdin);", isso no Windows, para Linux, o comando é diferente.